# How to get POST variables and data without a form?

Tags: php

I would like to use something like this `http://example.com/index.php?key=pebble` and then perform an action if "pebble" is the data for the key variable. What I have right now for code is

```
<?php
$key = $_POST['key'];
if($key == "pebble") {
    $file = fopen("index.txt","w");
    echo fwrite($file, "Hello pebble!");
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I am assuming that is because it isn't posting but rather passing through variables. Can someone help with how to post the data through without needing an HTML form?

Comment: You're using a completely wrong method. Take a look at the cURL library. A few queries to your favorite search engine would get you to the solution you want

Comment: I appreciate the point in the proper direction :) Thank you very much

Comment: That's not a POST request, it's a GET. Change `$key = $_POST['key'];` to `$key = $_GET['key'];`. GET requests pass variables in the URI, POST requests have an additional body to the request which contains the POSTed data.

Comment: You would need a `GET` instead of a `POST` if you're wanting to use `http://example.com/index.php?key=pebble` you could also use `$key = $_REQUEST['key'];` instead of `$key = $_POST['key'];` Using `$_REQUEST` will allow you to keep your code intact, should your form's method ever change from `GET` to `POST`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I was wrong in understanding the requirements ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use `GET` instead of a `POST`

if you're wanting to use `http://example.com/index.php?key=pebble`

You could also use:

`$key = $_REQUEST['key'];` instead of `$key = $_POST['key'];`

Using `$_REQUEST` will allow you to keep your (handler) code intact, should you ever want to change your form's method from `GET` to `POST` and vice-versa.

However, using `GET` could hold a security risk down the road, should you want to implement it for a DB, if proper measures are not taken to properly sanitize/escape user input.

**General rule of thumb:** Never trust user input.

Comment: POST is no safer than GET

Comment: I never said one was safer than the other. @user574632

Comment: **General rule of thumb: Never trust user input.** @user574632

Comment: Some good points. Side note; never trust user input, database data, SESSION variables or COOKIE's. In-fact, stay in doors, don't talk to anyone, it's not safe out there anymore. Aaaaaagghhh

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the type of world we live in now, and have to deal with. @PaparazzoKid Yet, ski season is upon us, so no way this guy's staying indoors ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, lucky you! [jealous face]

Comment: You guys have no ski hills your way? I remember you (UK) had quite a bit of snow a year or so ago. Apparently there are no snow tires being sold there, and it was absolute mayhem :( Stay safe @PaparazzoKid

Comment: We're such wimps. When snow comes down in UK we don't know what to do it with. As soon as somebody sees one snow flake the whole country is shuts down in panic. Be lucky!

Comment: Well, that's kind of what happens around here too, at first snowfall. People freak over the first four snowflakes, even with snow tires on, go figure. But hey... try and get yourself a snowboard off the web and use it (almost anywhere) whenever a pile of snow does fall again. Or... do like we used to do when we were younger, hang on cars/buses bumpers! Just don't lose your mittens! Cheers @PaparazzoKid

Answer (score 0):

You need get your data with `$key = $_GET['key'];`because you are sending information with querystring variables.

Answer (score 0):

if the data you need is sent in a `GET` request which means it appears in `name=value` combinations in the URL like

`http://example.com/index.php?key=pebble`

The correct way to get the value of the name key is to use the following

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
echo $key; // OUTPUT: pebble
```

In your example, you're using `POST` and not `GET`, while infact, it's `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Just change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

```
 $key = $_GET['key'];
```

That seems to be what you are looking to do.